# html can you combine 2 symbols or another way to get the same effect

Tags: javascript, html

I want the &#9645 (rectangle) symbol and &#9711 (circle) symbol in the same spot
Im trying to put in a optimization math problem and the question has to deal with a rectangle being inside a circle and i wanted to display that.

js fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tmanrocks999/d0htbokn/

html/ js:

```js
 var userInput = prompt("Please enter your optimization problem: ", "");
 
  if(userInput.includes("Determine the area of the largest rectangle that can be inscribed in a circle of radius"));
  document.write("&#9645;"+" &#9711;"+"<br>");
  document.write("x"+"2".sup()+" + "+"y"+"2".sup()+" = 16 ");
  //
  document.write("");
```

```html
<html>
<body>

Determine the area of the largest rectangle that can be inscribed in a circle of radius 4.
</body>
</html>
```

I expect my output to have the rectangle and circle in the same position not next to each other. but my current output they are next to each other not overlapping like i want.

Comment: You will need to look into using the positioning system from CSS to have the items overlap. By default, items will flow such that they take up the space that they need and not overlap (which is the typical case). https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative could be to create your rectangle or circle as a SVG. Something like:

```html
<svg width="30" height="30">
    <rect width="30" height="30" style="fill:rgba(0,0,255, 0);stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />
    <circle cx="15" cy="15" r="10" style="fill:rgba(0,0,255, 0);stroke-width:2;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)"  />
</svg>
```

[Check out some easy examples](https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_rect.asp)

Answer (score 1):

For that, you can use CSS `position` property as below
You can learn more about CSS positions [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)

> An element with position: absolute; is positioned relative to the
>   nearest positioned ancestor (instead of positioned relative to the
>   viewport, like fixed).

and to make your shapes look neat and clean, we can push the inside shape some pixels from the left side by using `left` property

```css
.parent{
  position : relative;
}
.child.c{   
  position: absolute;

}
.child.r{
  left : 2px;
  position : absolute;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<script>
 var userInput = prompt("Please enter your optimization problem: ", "");
 
  if(userInput.includes("Determine the area of the largest rectangle that can be inscribed in a circle of radius"));
  document.write("<span class='parent'><span class='child r'>&#9645;</span>"+" <span class='child c'>&#9711;</span></span>".fontsize(4)+"<br>");
  document.write("x"+"2".sup()+" + "+"y"+"2".sup()+" = 16 ");
  //
  document.write("");
</script>
Determine the area of the largest rectangle that can be inscribed in a circle of radius 4.
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT**
if you find difficulty displaying in different screens you can go for SVG 
as suggested by riorudo
However, I have made a few modifications based on your needs

Have a look at [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f210yweh/3/)

Comment: can i make it look more neat? https://jsfiddle.net/tmanrocks999/d0htbokn/   I mess around with it some more but the rectangle should be in the circle it looks bad right now

Comment: have a look at this, https://jsfiddle.net/oeav637d/ now it looks cleaner

Comment: i messed it up somehow    https://jsfiddle.net/tmanrocks999/1aofLxw7/20/   it worked at school now its bad. ill try to fix it. ty for the help. now im working on making a nice square root symbol with a bar over it

Comment: if you've messed it up, you can still click on the link I posted it will be what I gave you

Comment: its very weird. it works at school but at my house its diffrent

Comment: all good i have 2 versions of it now       http://prntscr.com/pqfh2z  . so weird at home it looks like this mabey its the browser version idk but they should be the same

Comment: are you using the same java script i gave?

Comment: if still, problem persists try using SVG https://jsfiddle.net/f210yweh/3/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what type of solution you're looking for, but you can always use CSS to position the shapes exactly where you want within the parent div or within the document itself.

The example below just uses position: absolute and other relevant position CSS attributes to force the two shapes to overlap.

Check out this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mzack5020/k1uz6xcn/1/)

```html
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        .stacked {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0px;
            left: 0px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <script>
        var userInput = prompt("Please enter your optimization problem: ", "");

        if (userInput.includes("Determine the area of the largest rectangle that can be inscribed in a circle of radius"));
        document.write("<div class='stacked'>&#9645;</div>" + " <div class='stacked'>&#9711;</div>" + "<br>");
        document.write("x" + "2".sup() + " + " + "y" + "2".sup() + " = 16 ");
        //
        document.write("");
    </script>
    Determine the area of the largest rectangle that can be inscribed in a circle of radius 4.
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The position property of CSS will be very helpful here. It can be helpful for positioning the HTML element at the place you desire. The position property is used to determine the kind of positioning you want to use for the container as either 'absolute' or 'relative'. If you set the position property as 'absolute', the style sheet would position them one underneath the other using CSS.